# JS Function stored in variable not callable

Tags: javascript, function

I have built a Typewriter effect for my website and i want to provide the ability to pass some condition for certain Typewriter effects so they only get executed when that condition holds.

Im trying to achieve that by passing a function to the constructor and i want to call that function later on. Unfortunately, this does not work for whatever reason.. You can find a reproducible example below.

Structure is like the following:

```
const Typewriter = function(..., condition, ....) {
   ....
   this.condition = condition;
   ....
   this.type()
}
```

And i am passing the function like so:

```
const conditionFunc = function() { ... }

new Typewriter(...., conditionFunc, ...);
```

When i want to call that function later on inside `Typewriter.prototype.type()` where i have access to the Typewriter Object using `this`, i cannot call it.

`type` is just a function which does the typing effect.

```
Typewriter.prototype.type = function() {
    // Add char to the element
    this.currValue = this.wordsToPrint.substring(0, this.currValue.length + 1);
    this.element.innerHTML = this.currValue;

    // console.log(this.condition()) gives error....
    setTimeout(() => this.type(), 80);
}
```

I try to call the function inside `type()` like so: `this.condition()` but it says this is not a function...
When i try `this.condition`, then it obviously returns the functions name and body without calling anything.

In my anger i have tried stuff like `var test = this.condition` and `test()` but this results in the same error...

I really dont know why it gives that error because `typeof(this.condition)` returns `function` obviously...

Thanks for any help!

---

I will try to give some minimal reproducible example by providing the script code:

```js
const Typewriter = function(element, wordsToPrint, condition) {
  this.element = element;
  this.wordsToPrint = wordsToPrint;
  this.condition = condition;
  this.currValue = '';
  this.type();
}

// Method for the typing effect
Typewriter.prototype.type = function() {
  // Add char to the element when condition holds
  if (this.condition()) { // This is the critical point in the code
    this.currValue = this.wordsToPrint.substring(0, this.currValue.length + 1);
    this.element.innerHTML = this.currValue;
  }

  setTimeout(() => this.type(), 80);
}

// Set up Typewriters after DOM is loaded
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init);


function init() {
  const someElement = {
    element: document.querySelector("h1"),
    content: document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML
  }

  // Clear text of elements before effect
  someElement.element.innerHTML = '';

  const conditionFunc = function() {
    return true;
  }

  // Create Typewriters
  new Typewriter(someElement.element, someElement.content, conditionFunc);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>This should be typed in a Typewriter effect</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This should indeed work. Please post a [mcve] that allows us the reproduce the problem.

Comment: This produces an error.

Comment: Getting a *`SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`* from your code. Please provide an *executable* example

Comment: Provided that you fix the small syntax errors that you have this seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/9jzwfd0y/

Comment: Just tried your script and it works fine. I just changed the function body to `{ return true}`. However in your example there are 3 things to correct in your `someElement` object: You're not closing the `"` double quote in your first querySelector (`element: document.querySelector("h1)`), it is also missing a comma after that, and there is a `;` after the `content` property which you should remove. It should work fine if you correct those

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once some errors are corrected (a error syntax after "h1 and bad separators in a list), it works for me... try to press in the run button:

```js
const Typewriter = function(element, wordsToPrint, condition) {
   this.element = element;
   this.wordsToPrint = wordsToPrint;
   this.condition = condition;
   this.currValue = '';
   this.type();
}

// Method for the typing effect
Typewriter.prototype.type = function() {
   // Add char to the element when condition holds
   if (this.condition()) {  // This is the critical point in the code
      this.currValue = this.wordsToPrint.substring(0, this.currValue.length + 1);
      this.element.innerHTML = this.currValue;
   }

   setTimeout(() => this.type(), 80);
}

// Set up Typewriters after DOM is loaded
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init);
function init() {
   const someElement = {
    element: document.querySelector("h1"),
    content: document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML,
   };

   // Clear text of elements before effect
   someElement.element.innerHTML = '';

   const conditionFunc = function() { return Math.random() > 0.5 ? true : false; }
   // Create Typewriters
   new Typewriter(someElement.element, someElement.content, conditionFunc); 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
   <h1>This should be typed in a Typewriter effect</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Bottom line: use fiddles :)

If you still have any problem please post comments.

Answer (score 0):

also, you can just assign feather arrow functions to consts

```
    const myFunc = (arg1, agr2) => { //blah blah }
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked the difference from my original script to the one that i provided here and its basically that i have ***two*** Typewriter objects while one does not have any condition so i passed null into its constructor. (Most likely thats not the best way to do it, need to google if theres optional parameters in JavaScript...)

The `Typewriter.prototype.type()` function though, obviously runs for both Typewriters and thats why it tried to call `this.condition()` on the Typewriter object where condition is `null` which resulted in the error. It worked perfectly fine on the other Typewriter object which **has** a conditional function, but the first Typewriter object already caused the error before the second one could give any output to the console so i thought it's not working at all..

Pretty beginner's mistake, really sorry for that. Thanks for all your help though!